# How to deal with upload/download pop-up window

Tags: perl, selenium

I am automating a website using Perl `WWW::Selenium`.
I want to know how can I handle the pop-up window which comes after clicking an upload or download button.

When an upload button is clicked, a dialog window opens to select the files.
When a download button is clicked, a dialog window opens to select the place where file is to be saved.

How the above scenarios can be automated in `WWW::Selenium`?

**CODE**

```
sub import_files()
{
   # http://mygengo.com/string/p/<proj_name>-1/admin/languages/import/en
   $url = $MYGENGO_STRING_PROJECT_URL . $_[0] . "-1" . $IMPORT_FILES;
   $sel->open($url);

   $sel->attach_file("class=qq-upload-button string-file-import", 
    "http://localhost/1.php"); # But this does not open the file browse window

   $sel->click("class=qq-upload-button string-file-import");
   $sel->wait_for_page_to_load(9000); 
}
```

Comment: in general it's quite hard to deal with them because that's no browser but os business...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload scenario can be easily solved by using `send_keys` command

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='upload-import-link']/input").send_keys(file)
```